# What's the VB.NET equivalent of this C# code for wiring up and declaring an event?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, silverlight, events

I'm working on a [tutorial to build a media player in Silverlight](http://www.85turns.com/2008/04/02/create-a-video-player-silverlight-2-part-1/) and am trying to wire up an `EventHandler` to the `timer.Tick` event of a `DispatchTimer` object so that the time of the video is synced with a `Slider` object.

The sample code is in C# and I can't for the life of me figure out the proper syntax in VB.NET with `RaiseEvent` and/or `Handles` to wire up the event.  Below is the relevant C# code.  I'll include comments on where I'm getting stuck.

```
private DispatchTimer timer;

public Page()
{
    //...
    timer = new DispatchTimer();
    timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(50);
    timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_Tick); // <== I get stuck here b/c
        // I can't do "timer.Tick += ..." in VB.NET
}

void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     if (VideoElement.NaturalDuration.TimeSpan.TotalSeconds > 0)
     {
         sliderScrubber.Value = VideoElement.Position.TotalSeconds /
             VideoElement.NaturalDuration.TimeSpan.TotalSeconds;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Like this:

```
AddHandler timer.Tick, AddressOf timer_Tick
```

Alternatively,

```
Private WithEvents timer as DispatcherTimer


Sub timer_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles timer.Tick

End Sub
```